# Include language array in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, arrays, internationalization, codeigniter-4

I receive the "language segment" from the url (I use CodeIgniter 4)

ex: [www.site.com/en/book](http://www.site.com/en/book)

I would like to load the relative translations array in the controller ready for the view... so I tried:

My controller:

```
$data['tran'] = array(require_once(APPPATH."/Language/en/file_lang.php"));
```

file_lang.php:

```
<?php
//english
$lang = array();

$lang['t1'] = "Description";
$lang['t2'] = "list";
$lang['t3'] = "Contact";
$lang['t4'] = "Write";
$lang['t5'] = "Views";
$lang['t6'] = "Cities";
```

In my view

```
echo ($tran['t1']);
```

I receive this error: Undefined index: t1

Does not work... why?

Comment: You need to return the value for this to work. At the end of your `file_lang.php`, add: `return $lang;` (but remove the `array(...)` around the include/requre). An alternative would be to just require the file and after do: `$data['tran'] = $lang;`.

Comment: I don't know why I can load only one file in the controller: $data['tran'] = (require_once(APPPATH."/Language/en/file_lang.php")); then $data['menu'] = (require_once(APPPATH."/Language/en/file_lang2.php")); does not work.. I receive: ErrorException : Array to string conversion in PHP. Why?

Comment: If you have another issue, you should post another question with all details.